# Java crashing if i hit play in minecraft

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, technical-issues

I'm trying to play minecraft, but the java(i'm using javaw to run it), but not working while i click to play the message below is displayed:

> JNI error has ocurred, please check your installation and try again

I reinstalled java 3 times, and this error occurs again and again.
The hopper.minecraft.net server is down :\ (502 bad gatway) to report it

Comment: Do you mind pasting the whole log somewhere (ie. [PasteBin](http://pastebin.com)? It may have other information to describe your error as that alone just tells us a generic error has occurred.

Comment: Yes! I will upload now!

Comment: How strange it was in%AppData%\.minecraft but do not have the folder logs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> JNI error has occurred

This is a generic Java error. [It is caused when not all the required libraries for a Java program isn't present.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32285197/error-a-jni-error-has-occurred)

Rather than re-installing Java, have you tried reinstalling Minecraft (deleting the `.minecraft` folder and starting fresh) and the launcher?

> I reinstalled java 3 times, and this error occurs again and again.
>
> ```
> The hopper.minecraft.net server is down
> ```

Have you checked your internet connection?
This only seems to indicate that the launcher could not post an automated crash report.

Comment: Yes! All correctly but if i click "Play" same error!